# Process substitution not working with install-sh autoconfigure

Tags: bash, process-substitution

I have an issue that <() is not working for install-sh from autoconfigure it gives me this error

```
./install-sh -m 755 <(sed -e 's/string-to-replace/string-for-replace/g' somefile.txt) result.txt
./install-sh: /dev/fd/63 does not exist.
```

While this works fine

```
install -m 755 <(sed -e 's/string-to-replace/string-for-replace/g' somefile.txt) result.txt
```

Comment: Can you show the contents of `install-sh` ? and whats the difference between it and and `install`

Comment: check *[bd]ash -x install-sh -m ...* if `sed` string is successful passed as argument

Comment: I get the same error with [bd]ash ./install-sh ....

Comment: of course `bash -x` is just for debugging purposes. with this you can check if your script runs with right arguments, it will not fix anything